# Cut and Get Three First Number from ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby on Rails. I have randomize ID for a model and I want to get the first three number from the ID and as "order code" save it to the DB.

My model consist of: id, first_name, last_name, and order_code.

For instance, the ID is 901233 then I want to put the 901 to the order_code. How to achieve that?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can achieve it using one of the simple method

1. Take out first 3 chars from string

   ```
   901233.to_s[0..2]
   #=> "901"

   901233.to_s.chars.first(3).join
   #=> "901"
   ```

**Edit**

From @cary's comment

```
901233.to_s.each_char.first(3).join
```

to avoid creation of a temporary array

Comment: A small point. You could write your second method `901233.to_s.each_char.first(3).join`. Your second method creates a temporary array `901233.to_s.chars` (upon which `Array#first` is invoked). You can avoid the creation of that array by replacing `chars` with `each_char`, in which case `Enumerable#first` is invoked on the enumerator returned by `each_char`.

Answer (score -1):

If your id is a variable, you can truncate it:

```
In [101]: id = "901233"

In [102]: id[0:3]
Out[102]: '901'
```

If it's a number, you can convert it and do the same:

```
In [105]: str(id)[0:3]
Out[105]: '901'
```

So you could just do:

```
order_code = str(id)[0:3]
```

Answer (score -1):

in your model.rb

```
before_create do
  self.order_code = id.to_s[0..2]
end
```

Comment: I got this error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ']' subid = id[0:3] ^